# why I can't delete .next folder in nextjs project

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-fullstack

I run my nextjs project by

```
npm run dev
```

NOT

```
npm run build
```

but it automatically creates the .next folder. and later I tried to delete that folder, but it automatically generated again.
why??

I don't expect to generate the .next folder by this command:

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: Because thats how nextjs works, both build and dev commands generates (SSR stuff and other) files which will be stored in same `.next` directory but file contents will be different.

Comment: You can also add the directory to your .gitignore file if you don't want to track it

Comment: So what is the problem? don't delete it. it is because next works like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are running your project with

```
npm run dev
```

Once the project is launched, `.next` folder will be created to store page cache and some features to speed up your project. While project running, some files will be added to `.next` folder during your `dev` usage. If you delete you .next folder during usage, you will have `errors` on the pages - you should restart your `npm run dev`

Comment: Exactly what I needed, the bit about need to restart with npm run dev after deleting. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 5):

You can delete .next folder and when you do `npm run dev` again, it will recreate it